# find attack packets on darpa dataset

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture, intrusion-detection

I download inside tcpdump data of week5-monday of darpa dataset[(link)](http://www.ll.mit.edu/mission/communications/ist/corpora/ideval/data/1999/testing/week5/monday/outside.tcpdump.gz)
and download attack list on week 4 and 5 of darpa site[(link)](http://www.ll.mit.edu/mission/communications/ist/files/master-listfile-condensed.txt)

> (attack list say on time `04/06/1999 08:11:15`  duration `00:00:10` on des
>   ip `172.016.112.050` is `tcpreset` attack)

I want to find `tcpreset` attack packet on tcpdum so I open `tcpdump` with wireshark and filter packets that times between `8:11:15` and `8:11:25` (frame.time>`apr 6,1999 8:11:15` and frame.time>`apr 6,1999 8:11:25`)

problem: I cant find packet with `172.016.11.050` des ip on result!!!

Comment: mind the time difference (GMT -5)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a minute gap.

During the 1999 evaluations, a 1 minute gap was given to give chance for IDSs to detect attacks during week 2 for labeled attacks.